# Help with query statement

Tags: postgresql

**EDIT**

This query seems to work best so far.

```
select host,plugin_id,month,year, row_number() over (partition by plugin_id order by plugin_id) as plugin_split 
from table 
where risk in ('High') 
group by plugin_id,host,month,year 
order by plugin_id,host,month asc;
```

This seems to group all the plugin_id,host, and month together to make it easy to parse.

Would it be possible to only select hosts that have the same plugin_id for month 1 and 9? And then only for month 1 but not month 9? And then only for month 9 but not month 1? I was looking into parsing this with ruby if I couldn't do it in SQL. Not really a DBA any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
select host,risk,plugin_id,month,year from table where risk in ('High') group by plugin_id,host,risk,month,year;

     host      | risk | plugin_id | month | year 
---------------+------+-----------+-------+------
 172.20.10.122 | High |     10081 |     1 | 2014
 172.20.10.122 | High |     10081 |     9 | 2013
 172.20.10.51  | High |     10081 |     1 | 2014
 172.20.10.52  | High |     10081 |     1 | 2014
 172.20.10.53  | High |     10081 |     1 | 2014
 172.20.10.53  | High |     10081 |     9 | 2013
 172.20.10.54  | High |     10081 |     9 | 2013
 172.20.10.55  | High |     10081 |     9 | 2013
 172.20.10.56  | High |     10081 |     1 | 2014
 172.20.10.56  | High |     10081 |     9 | 2013
 172.20.10.57  | High |     10081 |     1 | 2014
 172.20.10.58  | High |     10081 |     1 | 2014
 172.20.10.58  | High |     10081 |     9 | 2013
 172.20.10.59  | High |     10081 |     1 | 2014
 172.20.10.59  | High |     10081 |     9 | 2013
 172.20.10.60  | High |     10081 |     1 | 2014
 172.20.10.60  | High |     10081 |     9 | 2013
 172.20.10.61  | High |     10081 |     1 | 2014
 172.20.10.61  | High |     10081 |     9 | 2013
 172.20.10.62  | High |     10081 |     1 | 2014
```

Answer (score 1):

You can self join the table so that on the left there are the hosts for month 1, on the right for month 9:

```
SELECT host, risk, plugin_id, month, year
  FROM your_table t1
  JOIN your_table t2 ON t1.month = 1 
                    AND t2.month = 9 
                    AND t1.host = t2.host 
                    AND t1.plugin_id = t2.plugin_id
 WHERE risk = 'High';
```

This will return the hosts where plugin_id is the same for the two months.  It is not exactly clear what the other queries should be - I imagine it is not like the plugin is the same for a given month.  Please edit your question with the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select host,risk,plugin_id, min(month) m1, max(month) m2 from table 
where risk in ('High') and month in (1,9)
group by plugin_id,host,risk
having count(distinct month)<=2
order by host,risk,plugin_id, m1, m2 desc
;
```